# Kaltura Flavor Switching

Tags: kaltura

I am currently using Kaltura HTML5 Player ver. 2.26. The [documentation](http://player.kaltura.com/docs/index.php?path=api#doSwitch) suggests that you can switch between video flavors via the "doSwitch" notification, like so:

```
kdp.sendNotification("doSwitch", { flavorIndex: 3 });
```

The video I am using has 6 different flavors according to `kdp.evaluate("{mediaProxy.kalturaMediaFlavorArray}")`, but running this with various different indices has no discernible effect. I would expect to see the `kdp` fire a `switchingChangeStarted` event, as happens when using the Source Selector plugin UI, but there's just silence.

Searching through the [github repo](https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=doSwitch) for `doSwitch`, I don't actually see it implemented anywhere. Is this some method a lost relic? If not, how do I get the `doSwitch` notification to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDP is the Kaltura flash player which has this notification for switching bitrates.
The notification is still being used internally when the chromeless flash player is loaded and the source selector button is clicked. But it doesn't look like a V2 player notification.

You could extend the player by adding a new plugin that will expose such a notification that will switch the source similar to how the source selector is doing it (sourceSelector.js::208):

```
_this.getPlayer().switchSrc( source )
```

Note that the list of sources could have sources that are not playable on desktop, you should not use those for switching.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of posterity, here is what I ended up doing, following Roman's suggestion. The plugin below is pretty much the bare minimum, but this does precisely what I want it to do.

In the embed, we need to declare the custom plugin:

```
kWidget.embed({
  ...
  "flashvars": {
    ...
    "sourceExposure": {
      "plugin": true,
      "iframeHTML5Js": "js/sourceExposure.js"
    }
  }
}
```

In `js/sourceExposure.js`, we need to declare a plugin that provides a response to a custom event (here, "customDoSwitch"):

```
(function(mw,$) {
  mw.kalturaPluginWrapper(function() {
    mw.PluginManager.add( 'sourceExposure', mw.KBaseComponent.extend({

      setup: function() {
        var _this = this;

        this.bind('customDoSwitch', function(evt, flavorIndex) {
          var sources = _this.getSources().slice(0)
          if (flavorIndex >= sources.length) {
            _this.log("Flavor Index too large.");
            return;
          }
          _this.getPlayer.switchSrc(_this.getSources()[flavorIndex]);
        })
      },

      getSources: function() {
        return this.getPlayer().getSources()
      }
    }));
  });
})(window.mw, window.jQuery)
```

When we want to switch to a different flavor, we can now use the custom event and pass the flavor index:

```
kdp.sendNotification("customDoSwitch", 2) //switches to flavor index 2
```